# Single auxilliary verb before conjunction "and" vs. two auxilliary verbs around it

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, auxiliary-verbs, conjunction-reduction

Which one of these statements is correct or more appropriate or recommended?

- Alice is an artist and is very popular for her work.
- Alice is an artist and she is very popular for her work.
- Alice is an artist and very popular for her work.

How about these?

- I have read the document and have corrected the mistakes in it.
- I have read the document and I have corrected the mistakes in it.
- I have read the document and corrected mistakes in it.

How about these?

- I have read the document and have found it interesting.
- I have read the document and I found it interesting.
- I have read the document and found it interesting.

All those statements seem valid to me. But I am not a native English speaker. So I want to understand if all those statements are really valid both from grammatical point of view as well as from the point of view of popular usage, and if any one form is preferred to the others.

Comment: I don't know about popular usage, but they're all okay grammatically.  (Your last example, "I have read the document and found it interesting", is ambiguous in an interesting way, since one can't tell whether "found" is a past tense or a perfect participle.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the listed sentences are valid and grammatically correct. However, two of them could be considered redundant as they are repeating the same words that were used before.

The linked Wikipedia article explains very well what [*coordination in linguistics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_(linguistics)) is and how it works.

> - Sarah is [a CEO] and [proud of her job]. - NP (Noun Phrase) + AP (Adjective Phrase)
> - The president will [understand] and [agree]. - V (Verb) + V
> - The president will [understand the criticism] and [take action] - VP (Verbal Phrase) + VP

Contrast the above three sentences with the followings:

> - Sarah is a CEO and she is proud of her job.
> - The president will understand and he/she will agree.
> - The president will understand the criticism and he/she will take action.

Now, your examples:

> - Alice is an artist and (is) very popular for her work.
> - Alice is an artist and (she is) very popular for her work.
> - Alice is an artist and very popular for her work.
> - I have read the document and (have) corrected the mistakes in it.
> - I have read the document and (I have) corrected the mistakes in it.
> - I have read the document and corrected mistakes in it.
> - I have read the document and (have) found it interesting.
> - I have read the document and (I found) it interesting.
> - I have read the document and found it interesting.

You don't need to repeat the bracketed word (s).